# 'Spy Activity Spotted' in Android notification

Tags: notifications

I bought a new Galaxy S3 and downloaded *Frontline Commando: D-Day* from Play Store. I have not inserted the SIM card yet. I use my phone via wifi, for now.

Yesterday, I got a notification that **'Spy Activity Spotted! Terminate....'** for the game. Now, I am not sure as to why that happened. I decided to read the message further and clicked on the notification. Instead, it launched the game.

So I have two questions:
1. Is it a false positive? (considering I wasn't connected to WiFi or cellular network)
2. How do I read previous notifications once they have disappeared from notification panel?

Answer (score 6):

Judging by the details you have provided, there is nothing to be afraid of regarding the notification. The *spy activity* you mentioned is *never* an actual warning from the OS but a mere notification generated by the game to involve you in playing it. (Most probably you will be told that some enemy is spotted spying on you in an on-game mission, after the notification  is selected and the game is opened.) So after all, that notification is *NOT* a actual *positive* spyware warning. Nothing to worry.

You can't read previously cleared notifications of the notification bar. But you **might be** able to see the previous notification of your game if the game has a such a function in-built. Check for *Notifications* or *Mission Updates* in in-game menus. This, of course, is bit of a long shot. If there is no such option, those notifications also cannot be viewed.